# Undefined is not an object evaluating adapter.schema

Tags: react-native, watermelondb

I am trying to integrate `WatermelonDb` in my React Native App.
I am getting an error saying undefined is not an object(evaluating adapter.schema)

I followed this GitHub issue 
https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/issues/40
but it didn't gave any solution

I followed following steps for installation

```
yarn add @nozbe/watermelondb
yarn add @nozbe/with-observables
yarn add --dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
```

I created a `.babelrc` file and added following

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

I opened my project in Xcode

I created an empty `swift` file and when `Xcode` asked to create `Briding Header`, I created that as well

Here is the screenshott

[image]

I am using React Native 0.60 so I did not run the link command in the terminal.

I also created a separate project where I tried running `react-native link @nozbe/watermelondb` in which `React Native` version is 0.60.5
and when running the app on iOS simulator, react native throw a warning saying linking happens automatically so for unlinking I ran `react-native unlink @nozbe/watermelondb`  but I still face the same issue whether linked or not.

Here is my sample code

```
import {appSchema, tableSchema} from '@nozbe/watermelondb';

export const mySchema = appSchema({
  version: 1,
  tables: [
    tableSchema({
      name: 'users',
      columns: [
        {name: 'user_name', type: 'string'},
        {
          name: 'age',
          type: 'number',
          isOptional: true,
        },
        {name: 'is_male', type: 'boolean'},
      ],
    }),
  ],
});

import {Model} from '@nozbe/watermelondb';
import {field} from '@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators';

export default class Users extends Model {
  static table = 'users';

  @field('user_name') userName;
  @field('age') age;
  @field('is_male') isMale;
}
```

In index.js

```
const database = new Database({
  modelClasses: [Users],
});
```

Comment: Hi did you get any help on this?